# Querying feature info for L.esri.dynamicMapLayer "bbox must be specified"

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I have a Leaflet map in which I am displaying an Esri ArcGIS REST layer, using `L.esri.dynamicMapLayer()`. The code that initializes this layer is passed the URL to the service and a comma-separated list of layers to be displayed - which service and which layers is configured by the user.

My task is to provide a means by which the user can click on the map and obtain feature information for the nearby facilities. I had been looking at `L.esri.query()`, which was simply inappropriate.

Looking at `L.esri.DynamicMapLayer`, I see that it has a function `identify()`, which should return an IdentifyFeatures object. But I'm not having any luck with using it.  Everything I try results in a

> bbox must be specified

error.

The documentation for dynamicMapLayer is here: [dynamic-map-layer.html](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/dynamic-map-layer.html)
It includes:

> Returns a new L.esri.services.IdentifyFeatures object that can be used
>   to identify features on this layer. Your callback function will be
>   passed a GeoJSON FeatureCollection with the results or an error.

```
dynamicMapLayer.identify()
  .at(latlng, latlngbounds, 5)
  .run(function(error, featureCollection){
     console.log(featureCollection);
});
```

Note that .at() is called with a latlong object, a latlngbounds object, and "5".

But the documentation for the IdentifyFeatures object is here: [identify-features.html](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet//api-reference/tasks/identify-features.html)

And it's documentation for at() is:

> at( latlng)   this    Identifies feautres at a given

Only one argument. No second bounds argument, or third numeric argument, simply a LatLng. The LatLng links to the Leaflet code, indicating that it's an L.latLng object, containing a lat and a lng property.

The example code for IdentifyFeatures is even more confusing:

```js
L.esri.identifyFeatures({
  url: 'http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldTimeZones/MapServer'
})
.on(map)
.at([45.543, -122.621])
.layers('visible:1')
.run(function(error, featureCollection, response){
    console.log("UTC Offset: " + featureCollection.features[0].properties.ZONE);
});
```

Here, we're not passing a L.latLng object, we're passing an array.

What gives? How am I supposed to use this?

---

After some clarification as to what the proper arguments should be, I passed a single LatLng object, and continued to get the "bbox must be specified" error.

Tracking this down into the JS libraries, I discovered that this error message is being returned by the server. The esri-leaflet is building up the URL below, sending it to our customer's ArcGIS REST server, and getting back the error.

```
https://gis.elided.invalid/arcgis/rest/services/Secure/Korweb_App/MapServer/export/identify?sr=4326&layers=all&tolerance=3&returnGeometry=true&imageDisplay=431%2C600%2C96&mapExtent=-75.59185445308685%2C40.99650425834298%2C-75.58954238891602%2C40.998933489018704&geometry=-75.59079766273499%2C40.998492185433854&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&f=json
```

I'm eliding the actual URL because one, this is a customer's production site, and I haven't permission to allow anyone else to access, and because it's behind an IP-filtering firewall, and nobody could access it, anyway.

So, we're down to the real question - should this URL have worked? Is there a bbox argument that should have been passed, that was somehow left out? Or is this a correct URL, and there's something on the server that has been misconfigured?

---

OK, it was something stupid.

Esri's ArcGIS REST API uses a base URL that looks like this:

```
https://tmservices1.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/LiveFeeds/Earthquakes/MapServer
```

To which it appends the various actions that are requested. To export an image, you call:

```
https://tmservices1.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/LiveFeeds/Earthquakes/MapServer/export/????
```

To do an identify, you call:

```
https://tmservices1.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/LiveFeeds/Earthquakes/MapServer/identify/????
```

The configuration we were building our map from was handed a URL that ended in "/export". As a result, when we did an identify, we called a URL that included "/export/identify", so we weren't asking for an identify, we were asking for an export, and were passing invalid arguments.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to loop back and explain the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the `L.esri.dynamicMapLayer` code snippet is incorrect.  `at()` expects an [`L.latLng`](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/blob/master/src/Tasks/IdentifyFeatures.js#L28-L33) object to be passed as the sole argument.  thanks for pointing out the issue.  i've [corrected](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-doc/commit/d387587f8c6fba9ab28ead64671f5f51c5f06ad1) the problem and will push the fix to the live site soon.
2. the identifyFeatures code snippet and [live sample](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/identifying-features.html) both provide valid examples of how to work with the task.
3. its a leaflet convention that a cast L.latLng object and a raw [lat,lng] array can be used interchangeably.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng

> All Leaflet methods that accept LatLng objects also accept them in a simple Array form and simple object form (unless noted otherwise)

Comment: So why, when I pass a LatLng object, do I get a "bbox must be specified" error.

Comment: i don't see the same problem in our live sample, so you'll have to show me some code of your own (preferably in a jsbin or fiddle) if you need some help debugging.

Comment: Can't do a jsbin or fiddle because we're hitting a arcgis server that you'd not have access to. I've posted the actual hhtp request, above.

Comment: do you see the same problem when you swap in a public sample service url in your own code?  if so, a fiddle pointing at the new service would work just fine.

Comment: Haven't, yet.  That's the next thing to try, once I get out of the damned meetings I'm being dragged into.